# XML Error of Too Many Root Elements

Tags: xml

I am getting error

> There are multiple root elements

Below is my code, I have seen other replies on this forum for my question but nothing is helping me. Please check my code and let me know where I am performing wrong operation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<DAM>
    <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>EPS_JPG_PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>
    <xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>
    <xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>11</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>
</DAM>  
<DAM>
    <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>EPS_REGULAR_PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>
    <xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>
    <xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>11</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>
</DAM>
<DAM>
    <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>JPEG_PSEERE140P000001.jpg</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>
    <xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>
    <xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>11</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>
</DAM>
<DAM>
    <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>LV_PSEERE140P000001.jpg</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>
    <xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>
    <xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>12</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>
</DAM>
<DAM>
    <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>PN_PSEERE140P000001.jpg</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>
   <xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>
   <xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>13</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>
</DAM>
<DAM>
 <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>PV_PSEERE140P000001.jpg</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME><xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME><xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>14</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID></DAM>
.........
```

Comment: Well yes, your XML is invalid. (I wouldn't say it's "code" - it's just an XML file.) You open a `xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME` element, then close it, then open a `xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME` element. What created this XML file? (I'd also strongly recommend formatting it for readability... having all the data on a single line is *awful* for readability.)

Comment: Please format your xml. You cannot expect anyone to help you with only one very long line of xml.

Formatting will help you find the error, too.

Comment: A valid XML document has ***one root node*** only - not dozens of it. You need to put all your `<DAM>` nodes into some root node, e.g. `<ROOT><DAM> .... </DAM> .... </ROOT>` to get a valid XML

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all - you have too many (= more than one) root elements (`<DAM>`). Change your file to a structure like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<root>
    <DAM>
        <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>EPS_JPG_PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>
        <xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>
        <xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>11</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>
    </DAM>  
    <DAM>
        <xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>EPS_REGULAR_PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_DEV_RELATIONS.DRE_FNAME>
        <xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>PSEERE140P000001.eps</xcnF_IMGKOMP.PKOM_NNAME>
        <xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>11</xcnF_DERIVATE.DEV_ID>
    </DAM>
...
</root>
```